# my facebook application redirects to apps.facebook.com:80 in safari which causes an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

i  am using facebook c# sdk. when i try to open my application (i logged out from facebook), after i login, it redirects me to http://apps.facebook.com:80/xxx/?locale=en_GB which causes an error

"Too many redirects occurred trying to open “http://apps.facebook.com:80/xxx/?locale=en_GB”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page."

this happens only in safari. what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download version 4.1.1. This error was caused by a change Facebook made. We patched the SDK in V4.1.1 and the issue should be solved. Let me know if you continue to have the problem.